# Convert jQuery AJAX API .done() and .fail() functions to AngularJS $http

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am fairly new to Angular and am working on incorporating an existing jQuery AJAX API into Angular.

Right now I am doing stuff like:

```
$.myApi.login('username', 'password').done(function(result) {
    //do stuff
    $scope.$apply(); //apply changes to Angular app
}).fail(function(result) {
    //do stuff if login failed
    $scope.$apply(); //apply changes to Angular app
});
```

Is there a cleaner way to integrate APIs like this than just writing `$scope.$apply()` everywhere? Can I integrate with Angular's `$http` somehow without ditching the existing functions and just making raw AJAX requests to the URLs (i.e. can I reuse the existing API's functions directly)?

Comment: Yes, just go ahead and use $http. Here is the documentation url https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @PSL So in this particular example, I would not even call `$myApi.login()` and instead just call the URL that `$myApi.login()` would have called, instead using `$http.post('/loginUrl/')` etc.? Is that pretty much the cleanest way to do it? Or can I reuse the jQuery functions somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to use jquery ajax instead of angular. Then you are into the same business of scope.apply() right. You can do the ajax call with angular $http itself. If you really do want to use it then you would need to use deferred pattern instead of scop.apply to resolve/reject the promise.

Comment: I guess I just want to try to avoid rewriting all the API functions in Angular. I was hoping there would be some sort of plug and play way to do this, but based on your comments I guess I either have to make the raw requests using $http or just use $scope.$apply().

Comment: Yes you can either rewrite the service in angular or create a wrapper in angular and wrap it with angular $q deferred pattern or just the easiest `$scope.$apply()`. That is what i could think about, there might be another alternative but these are the only ones that comes to my mind.